# The generalization of a phenomenon?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry

Consider a polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^n$. When we try to maximize a linear function within this polyhedron, the optimal solution may be unique (vertex) or not unique (edge or face). Observe that an edge or a face always contains vertices. Denote by $A$ the set of points that are uniquely optimal for some linear functions. ($A$ is in fact the set of vertices). Then for any linear function $i$, denote by $B_i$ the set of maximizers. It must be the case that $A\cap B_i \neq \varnothing$.

In other words, the optimal solution is either unique, or are the convex combination of the points that are sometimes uniquely optimal.

Is there a generalization of this? For example, a theorem describing the above phenomena, or a result regarding more general objective function and/or feasible region?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I'm reminded of the "maximum principle" for Harmonic functions, which has many discrete analogues. (But maybe this is just on my mind because I've recently been watching Keenan Crane's excellent lectures on Discrete Differential Geometry.)